# Change inside URL with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a mothod to open and extract information form a website from aspecific URL but I wuld like to be able after I write down the URL 3 new URLs to be generated on the base of the exisiting one:

For example: `IE.navigate "http://www.website.com/case/lesson/number/index.asp?"`

from this URL I would like the VBA to generate another URL in which the number is changed with date everything stays the same, like; `IE.navigate "http://www.website.com/case/lesson/date/index.asp?"`

How can this be achived ?

Thanks

Comment: `Replace()` seems like a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Is the website.com/case always going to be the same?  You can always staticall assign the first part if so and the concatenate the second part like so:

```
Dim str as String
Dim str2 as String
Dim finalstr as String

str = "http://www.website.com/case"

str2 = "/lesson/date/index.asp?"

finalstr = str & str2
```

Comment: Problem is that the ser will add at once the whole URL which after that needs to be chaged, in the center of the URL